# SQL Server 2016 : query performance with join and without join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables TABLE1 AND TABLE2.

- TABLE1 has columns masterId, Id, col1, col2, category
- TABLE2 has columns Id, col1, col2

`TABLE2.Id` is primary key and `TABLE1.Id` is foreign key.

TABLE1.masterId is primary key of TABLE1.

TABLE1 has 10 million rows with Id 1 to 10 million and first 10 rows having category = 1

TABLE2 has only 10 rows with Id 1 to 10.

Now I want col1 and col2 values with category=1 (either from TABLE1 OR TABLE2 because the values are same in both tables)

Which among below 2 queries gives output faster?

Solution1:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2 
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.category = 1
```

Solution2:

```
SELECT T2.col1, T2.col2 
FROM TABLE2 T2 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T1.category = 1
```

Does Solution2 save Table Scan time on millions of rows of TABLE1.

**Limitation is:**
In my real db scenario, I can make Table1.Id  as non clustered index and Table1.category also non clustered index.  I cannot make Table1.Id as clustered index because I actually have another auto increment column as primary key in my Table1 in real scenario.  So please share your thoughts with this limitation.

Please confirm and share thoughts on this.

Comment: What database are you using ? Your tagged `sql-server` & `plsql` which contradicts each other

Comment: Sorry, I am using Ms SqlServer 2016

Comment: It is somewhat unusual to let a single query determine your schema design.  If it makes sense to have two tables, then go with that design and instead focus on making the second query faster using things like indices.

Comment: Storing the same data in two different tables is (almost) never a good idea.

Comment: "Which among below 2 queries gives output faster?"  This can be tested on your system. How can anyone know which of the 2 is faster if we do not have the data?

Comment: Yes but my scenario needs a master table with say 10 rows, and child table has many sets of these 10 rows with a different category. My real DB does not have category column in master table,   I have included it here for clarity of question.

Comment: My intention is to know if the inner join reduces table scan time on TABLE1 which has millions of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the existing indexes. With a nonclustered index on Id in T1, then the solution 2 might perform better than solution 1, that would require a complete table scan to select the rows with category1. If instead we also have a nonclustered index on Category, then the solution 1 will be faster, since it would only have to seek the nonclustered index to find the rows.

Without any index on Id on T1 a full scan would be required to find the T2.Id row, therefore there might be 10 full scan of T1 for solution 2 and 1 full scan on T1.Category for solution 1, so the solution 1 might be faster. But this depends on the query optimizer and a test the real case to see what are the actual execution plans would be the best way to answer.

But the way to go is to implement the right model and then proceed to create the indexes needed to make the query run fast.

Edit: adapted the answer according to the query edits.
Edit2: index coverage would be expensive and a 10 index seek on PK on table 1 would not cost so much.

Comment: But in my real db scenario, I can make Table1.Id  as non clustered index and Table1.category also non clustered index.  I cannot make Table1.Id as clustered index because I actually have another auto increment column as primary key in my Table1 in real scenario.  So please share your thoughts with this limitation.

Comment: I have now included primary key for TABLE1 to be clear. Also rectified my inner join condition.

Comment: Plz check the 2 queries now

Comment: @Mahen, a primary key index can be clustered or nonclustered. The PK index is clustered by default unless the table already has a clustered index. Consider all queries in your workload to choose the most appropriate clustered index. There are trade-offs involved.

Comment: @DanGuzman Sure. As my primary key is identity column, it is going to become clustered. So I will have to make Table1.category as non-clustered index and Table1.Id also non-clustered index.  So as sergiom said, Solution1 would be preferable for me.

Comment: @Mahen, identity or not, the PK index does not have to be clustered. The physical index properties are independent of the constraint it enforces. I'm not suggesting clustered is the best choice since it depends on many other factors.

Comment: Oh. But a comment from Gordon Linoff  in another answer below says, in MS SqlServer an Identity PrimaryKey will be Clustered Index. I will have to validate this.

Comment: @Dan Guzman you are right. I have validated this in MS SQL Server 2016.  What Gordon says holds good if I only try to do it with SSMS. But by writing a Create table query manually I am able to create Primary Key with Non-Clustered index on Identity column which auto increments. And I am able to create another column as clustered index. 
So this is a bug in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

### [Notice]

This answer was given for an older version of the question, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65263530/7

The scenario back then was:

- T2 also had a `category` column, and,
- the second query was:

```
  SELECT T2.col1, T2.col2 
  FROM TABLE2 T2 
  INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.categoryId = T2.category Id
  WHERE T2.category = 1
```

---

Assuming the only indices are the PKs, nope, Solution 2 will NOT avoid the table scan. Worse:

Solution 1
Full table scan

Solution 2
Full table scan on T2 (T2.category) and then nested loops (T2.category = T1.category)

Please, what are your goals here?

Comment: Sorry, rectified Solution2 where condition: 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.Id

Comment: Plz check the 2 queries now

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, this statement shows a lack of understanding of databases:

> first 10 rows having category = 1

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "first 10 rows".  In the context of your question, I think you mean "the 10 rows with the lowest values of the `id`".  However, the ordering *of the table* is still arbitrary from the perspective of the engine.  There are situations where a *clustered* index could reasonably be assumed to be a "table ordering", but there is never a guarantee that:

```
select *
from t;
```

returns data in a particular ordering *even with a clustered index*.

Two possible execution plans for the first query -- depending on the indexing -- are:

1. Scanning the table (i.e. reading millions of rows) and doing the test for each row.
2. Scanning an index on `category` and just fetching the rows that are needed.

In general, (1) would be much, much slower than (2) when the scanned rows is in the millions and the returned rows are just a few.  However, if this may not be true if a significant proportion of all records were returned.

I interpret your question as asking whether the second query could ever be faster than the first:

```
SELECT T2.col1, T2.col2 
FROM TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN
     TABLE1 T1 
     ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T1.category = 1;
```

The answer is "definitely faster than the scan".  This is a possible if you have an index on `Table1(id, category)`.  However, the query would be better written using `EXISTS`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t2.id and t2.category = 1
             );
```

I would expect this to be faster than the indexed version of the first query as well.  Even with an index on `(category)`, the database still has to fetch the data for the `select`.  If the data is on one page (as the "first" statement might suggest), then the two might be quite comparable.  However, it would be hard to measure the difference in performance with the correct indexing on `table1`.

A note about clustered indexes in SQL Server.  If the `id` is an `identity` primary key and there is no other clustered index, then it is automatically used as the clustered index.

Comment: Yes, by saying first 10 rows I just wanted to convey the first 10 rows inserted from Table2 to Table1 with category=1 and auto increment primary key masterId

Comment: @If you have an `identity` primary key in SQL Server, then it is the clustered index.  That will might make the second approach marginally faster than the first, even with an index on `category`, but the difference would be very small either way.

Comment: Okk. I will definitely prefer identity PrimaryKey instead of creating unique primary key myself for every insert.  And after having non clustered index on Category column, I understand as you said, Solution2 will be marginally faster, but the difference will be very small. As the difference is very small, I will keep Solution1 which is in place with already around 6 joins with other tables.      Just relying on non clustered index on category which will avoid full Table scan on Table1 with huge data.  Hope my thought is valid.

Comment: I have validated this in MS SQL Server 2016.  What you said holds good if I only try to do it with SSMS. But by writing a Create table query manually I am able to create Primary Key with Non-Clustered index on Identity column which auto increments. And I am able to create another column as clustered index. 
So this is a bug in SSMS.

Comment: So with this understanding, I will prefer Making Table1.masterId  as Identity column and Primary Key with NonClustered index. And make Table1.category as Clustered index. Hope this will give much better performance compared to category being non-clustered.

Comment: @Mahen . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to in your previous comment.  The identity primary key is a clustered index *when no other clustered index is defined*.  You can create a secondary index on any columns, including those used for the primary key.

Comment: Yes, identity primary key is Clustered by default, but it is not mandatory to be Clustered I mean. I am able to create it as NonClustered also, provided I create table with a manually written query but not SSMS.